# How to filter the data based on selected tab using mat-tab in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend

I am trying to figure out how to filter data based on selected tab's value using `mat-tab` [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview). For example, I would like to have a tab panel with three tabs of city: `ALL`, `LA`, `SF`. If users click in the `ALL` tab, it will show all the data using `mat-card` [here](https://material.angular.io/components/card/overview). If users select `LA`, it will only display persons in LA, et.al.

By far, I only can show all the data without filtering. Here is the minimal codes what I have done:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let user of users">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>{{user.id}}</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>{{user.city}}</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Here is example of data:

```
const Users = 
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "person1",
      "first_name": "Mike",
      "last_name": "Patty",
      "city": "LA"
    },
    {
      "id": "person2",
      "first_name": "Mike2",
      "last_name": "Patty2",
      "city": "LA"
    },
    {
      "id": "person3",
      "first_name": "Mike3",
      "last_name": "Patty3",
      "city": "SF"
    },
    {
      "id": "person4",
      "first_name": "Mike4",
      "last_name": "Patty4",
      "city": "SF"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to display data responsive to tabs? I appreciate your advice and help.

Comment: You can use selectedTabChange output event and run your filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every tab change, you can get the `selectedTabChange` event. With this event, you will filter your users.

in html file -

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tabLabel of matTabLabels" label="{{tabLabel}}">
    <mat-card *ngFor="let user of selectedUsers">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>{{user.id}}</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>{{user.city}}</mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

in .ts file -

```
  selectedUsers: any;
  matTabLabels = ['ALL', 'LA', 'SF'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedUsers = this.Users.users;
  }

  tabChanged(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.index != 0) {
      const filterText = event.tab.textLabel;
      this.selectedUsers = this.Users.users.filter((user: any) => {
        return user.city === filterText;
      });
      console.log(this.selectedUsers);
    } else {
      this.selectedUsers = this.Users.users;
    }
  }
```

working stackBlitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qehpkb?file=src/app/tab-group-basic-example.ts

Comment: Consider using matTabContent to lazy load content. Also mat-chip could be better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the 'right' way is probably to use [Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes), but personally I find this a bit heavy handed for simple applications. Instead I like to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and do something like this:

html:

```
<button (click)='cityFilter = "LA"'>Los Angeles</button>

<div *ngFor="let user of getUsers(userlist.users)">
    {{user.first_name}}
    {{user.last_name}}
    {{user.city}}
  </div>
```

ts:

```
cityFilter: string;
userlist: any = {
    users: [
      {
        id: 'person1',
        first_name: 'Mike',
        ......

getUsers(users):any[] {
  if (!this.cityFilter) return users;
  return users.filter(u => u.city === this.cityFilter);
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8s3qfe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts